# Jquery Templates to populate META data?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates, meta-tags

I am using the jquery template to populate the majority of content on my site, I'm pulling in data from JSON files and displaying them.

I was asked to populate the meta tag = og:image in the header using images pulled from the json files.  I am just not sure if I can populate that using jquery templates?

Or another way of pulling in the json data and setting the Meta tag to a 'variable'?

Comment: you can append meta tags to `$('document')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe...

First, pull in your JSON and set your image url to a variable.

```
 var imageurl = "www.site.com/image.png";
 $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content','imageurl');
```